# Multiple variants in one png- Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, png

I have an android project with this png file. Why does it have 4 different permutations and how do I select which one I want. In one project I have it displays a more square version and in the other it displays a more stretched version. How does the xml decide which version of the png to take. How do I manually tell it which one to select?

This is what the image looks like when I open it in android studio:
[image]

Comment: It's likely a 9-patch image (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html). Open it outside of Android Studio and see how it looks.

Comment: As @Computerish said, it is a `9 patch`. It works by setting "stretchable areas". You are seeing its behaviour in the `draw9patch` tool, A nice tutorial is found [here](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/)